# Continuously Insert Data to Database through asmx Web Service

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a web service (hosted on IIS) that insert data to database(Xampp)

```
[WebMethod]
public void Insert(int a)
{
        string query = "INSERT INTO result (A) VALUES('" + a + "')";          

        if (this.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);   
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
}
```

The first time I consume this web service it works charm, but for the second time when it tries consume this service again, it returns an error message

**"The operation has timed out"**

on my coding

```
s1.Insert(a);
```

The Web service works correctly again when I restart my web service in IIS, but it is not going to work as it has to work continuously. Any hopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I can see could be your this object that remains for second call but it could not open connection.

Make object of your class instead of using this.

e.g

```
[WebMethod]
public void Insert(int a)
{
        string query = "INSERT INTO result (A) VALUES('" + a + "')";          
        YourClass obj = new YourClass();
        //Open connection here
        if (obj.OpenConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);   
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Problem in opening connection");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The new problem occurred, that is, the connection is not valid to open. In short, i cant even open the connection as assigning the class object..

Comment: I think the problem isn't related to the connection, but IIS itself. I created an HelloWorld function, and I got the same problem as too.

Comment: Hi there, I've figured out the problem, its actually due to the IIS default configuration where it can only handle one connection at one time. Its just the configuration problem, but still, thanks for your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you have a problem in the connection with the server, i think it take too much time in opening the connection to the server and this causes the time out, so you have to debug this case and ensure that the connection to the server is ok.

Comment: Im sorry but i dont think its the answer because the first INSERT command is done, where i already verified it through my database, but when it comes to second connection, it seems something stuck and i dont know what was that.. But thanks for your help ^^